# java lang Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have written a code which can reduce the grammatical boundaries for a text, but when I run the program this exception comes up

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

here is the class that i run,

```
public class paerser {
public static void main (String [] arg){
    LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser("grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
        lp.setOptionFlags("-maxLength", "500", "-retainTmpSubcategories");
        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
       GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
       String text = "John, who was the CEO of a company, played golf.";
       edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree parse = lp.apply(Arrays.asList(text));
       GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
       List<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
       System.out.println(tdl);

}
}
```

Updated,

here is the full stack trace ...

```
Loading parser from serialized file grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [1.5 sec].
Following exception caught during parsing:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.parse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:346)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:386)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.apply(LexicalizedParser.java:304)
    at paerser.main(paerser.java:19)
Recovering using fall through strategy: will construct an (X ...) tree.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be  cast to edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.apply(LexicalizedParser.java:317)
    at paerser.main(paerser.java:19)
```

Comment: Provide the stacktrace, and identify the line which throws the exception.

Comment: Post the full stack trace, not just error message

Comment: I already update the question with the full track trace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511169/java-lang-classcastexception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stacktrace shows that [ExhaustivePCFGParser's parse method](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/trac/browser/Public/public/curator-src/curator-annotators/stanford-parser/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/ExhaustivePCFGParser.java) is being used. It expects a List of HasWord objects. You are passing a list of String. Hence, the exception.

```
public boolean parse(List<? extends HasWord> sentence) { // ExhaustivePCFGParser
```