# What is causing this Java exception: RuntimeDelegateImpl incompatible with javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate?

Tags: java, rest, exception, jax-rs, apache-wink

I was wondering if anyone has any idea what could be causing this exception. When I google search it has almost no results. If anyone can help let met know.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.wink.common.internal.runtime.RuntimeDelegateImpl incompatible with javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:103)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.<clinit>(UriBuilder.java:71)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:235)
    ... 40 more
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511169/java-lang-classcastexception)

Comment: Your program is trying to cast an instance of `org.apache.wink.common.internal.runtime.RuntimeDelegateImpl` to type `javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate`, but the the former class does not implement the latter interface.  If you think the class *does* implement the interface then possibly you are running into an issue related to the two types being loaded by different classloaders.

Comment: can you show your code also?